# The meaning of "standing decision" in this text?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Brewer and his colleagues identify generalized trust in other nations,
>   or international trust, as a key component of public opinion about
>   world aﬀairs (Brewer 2004; Brewer et al. 2004; Brewer, Aday, and Gross
>   2005). Tey defne this form of trust as follows:
>
> International trust [is] a generalized belief about whether most
>   foreign countries behave in accordance with normative expectations
>   regarding the conduct of nations. Citizens with high levels of
>   international trust see the realm of world aﬀairs as a friendly
>   environment where trust and cooperation among nations are the norms;
>   in contrast, citizens with low levels of international trust see the
>   same realm as a hostile environment where all nations strive against
>   one another for advantage and readily defect from cooperative eﬀorts.
>   Put another way, international trust is a **standing decision** to give
>   other nations the beneft of the doubt, an assumption that most
>   countries are of good will and benign intentions. (Brewer et al. 2004,
>   96)
>
> Brewer and his colleagues conceptualize this **“standing decision”**
>   as a cognitive heuristic, or information shortcut, comparing it to
>   both social trust (or interpersonal trust) and political trust (or
>   trust in government). Te former, a generalized belief that one can
>   trust strangers (Uslaner 2002), provides individuals with a
>   **“standing decision** to give most people—even those whom one does not know from direct experience—the beneft of the doubt” (Rahn and
>   Transue 1998, 545). Te latter, a generalized orientation toward
>   government based on normative expectations of its operation, likewise
>   oﬀers individuals “a simple decision rule” for deciding how much
>   beneft of the doubt to give government (Hetherington and Globetti
>   2002, 254).

Is "standing decision" a separate phrase? I couldn't find it anywhere defined. What is its meaning?

Answer (score 3):

When we make a decision, we normally then put that decision into *action*. It may be that later we make a new decision, either if we find that the original decision is flawed or if we come into new information.

When a decision is challenged for either of those reasons, we may reconsider it. When we conclude that the original decision should remain in action, the idiomatic expression is to say that *the decision stands*.

So a "standing decision" is one which is *currently in action*.

The word "stand" has 33 different definitions in the Collins dictionary, but the one pertinent to this situation is:

> **Stand**
>   *Verb*
>   If a decision, law, or offer stands, it still exists and has not been changed or cancelled.

Comment: I think it also has similarities to a General/Standing Order (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_order)